# add Java library (.jar files) to flutter DESKTOP application

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to add a library written in java to flutter desktop application

I did research and I only found how to do it for android apps, some people mentioned that it is possible to do it for desktop but I couldn't find the process to do it.

I have to add it for windows and macos.

Comment: You can't use Java code via platform channels directly in any other operating system except android. For Windows you need to do native code in C++ and for MacOS you need to code natively in Objective C. To learn more, check this: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-c-plus-plus-tab

Comment: Or use FFI to call a C library, or if you have the Java source, port it to Dart.